# Problem of sets, how many did not indicate packages B or C?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve a problem involving sets. In the act of creating the sets and adding their elements, I manage to do it, but the question of the problem intrigues me, as I've never seen something like it, however, I tried to solve it my way, but I don't know if it's right. I'm probably wrong about the result I got, because in this interview problem, 40 people didn't choose a certain product, so I don't know what to do with these 40 people when it comes to solving the problem.

**Question:**
One company interviewed 300 of its employees about 3 packages A, B and C for a new product launch. The result was as follows:

160 indicated package A;

120 indicated package B;

90 indicated package C;

30 indicated packages A and B;

40 indicated packages A and C;

50 indicated packages B and C;

10 indicated the 3 packages.

How many did not indicate packages B or C?

**What I tried:**

1º Create the diagrams and add their elements

[image]

The question is: *How many did not indicate packages B or C?*

So to find how many didn't indicate $B$ or $C$, I have to add $50 + 40 + 10$, resulting in $100$. So, I got the result, $100$ didn't indicate B or C.
However, I'm probably wrong, as there are $40$ that didn't nominate any of the products, so it comes to mind: I must divide $40$ by the total number of sets (3), then add the product by the $100$ result I got, so $113$ people didn't nominate $B$ or $C$?

I am very confused on this problem. I can add the elements to the sets properly, but this question is a little difficult as I've never seen anything like this and I don't know how to do it correctly.

When the question says $B$ or $C$, I focus only on the unique elements of $B$ and $C$, so it's the elements $50 + 40 + 10$. But it's like I said, I'm not sure, and there's this issue of $40$ that didn't indicate any product.

**Conclusion**

I'm confused as I've never solved a problem like this, so I would like to understand how to actually solve this problem. If anyone can help me, I'm grateful.

**EDIT**

With the help of [Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) and [coffeemath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/483139/coffeemath), I realized that I was adding up the elements that were contained in $B$ and $C$, which goes against the issue of the problem. So, to solve it, all I had to do is add what's in  *just $A$*, in this case $100$, with $40$ that didn't choose any package.

Therefore:
$A(only) = 100$
$None = 40$

$Sum = 100 + 40 = 140$

*Q: How many did not indicate packages B or C?*

$A: 140$

Comment: I would read "How many did *not* indicate packages B or C?" as the $40$ who did not indicate anything   plus the $100$ who indicated A but neither B nor  C (a different $100$ compared with your $50+40+10$)

Comment: I think you added the wrong numbers. You want those outside both circles B and C. Thats the 100 in only A and the 40 who did not chose any.

Comment: That makes sense. Pure lack of attention. Thank you guys.

Comment: Bah, you can post this as an answer to this question, so that 1. users who come later also get helped, and 2. the question is marked answered to the website.